# Web-scraping Yell.com in Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-404, urllib

After reading a LOT, I have tried to do my first step in web scraping at yell website with *urllib* and *requests* but I get the same in both cases (404 not found).

The url is:

`url = https://www.yell.com/`

What I have tried:

- urllib package

```
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
print(f.read(100))
```

and

```
import urllib.request
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
opener.open(url)
```

- requests package

```
url = 'www.yell.com'
response = requests.get(url)
```

and

```
headers = {'Accept': 'text/html'}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

But i reach to the 404 error.

Comment: Add `User-Agent` in your `headers` for `requests` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using urllib

```
import urllib.request

url = 'https://www.yell.com/'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

print(response.read())
```

I would suggest you to use requests + beautifulsoup4 
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/
it will make your scraping life easier

Answer (score 0):

#You can use also selenium to avoid http errors
    from selenium import webdriver
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib.request

```
main_url = 'https://www.yell.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'write chromedriver path')
driver.get(main_url)
res = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res, 'html.parser')
headers = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }
request = urllib.request.Request(main_url, headers=headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)

print(response.read())
```